# Laravel get memory_limit error, when create folder from database

Tags: php, laravel, memory-limit

I Want to create folders based on `user_id` inside `/laravel/public/file/FolderUserXXX`.
If I have 1000 record user in database, i want to create 1000 folder inside the path (I need to create those folders because my server gets down and folders disappear).

I have created a job to execute that and I tried it in local with small data (is working) but in production I always get error `Allowed memory size of xxxxxxxxxxxxx bytes exhausted` (tried to allocate xxxxxxxx bytes). I add `memory_limit` until 4GB in `php.ini` but still get the problem.

Here is my code in `app/Console/Commands`

scenario:

`createfolder` job for user with `status >= 3` and `remark_restore` is `null`. On every successful creation `remark_restore` will change to 1. I tried to limit 1 data per job and run every minute, but I still get error.

But if I change `memory_limit` to `-1` only to run this job and then change it back to previous value, will be there any impact in the future for my web?

Any suggestion on how to prevent the `memory_limit` error?

```php
public function handle()
{
    try {
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 300000);
        ini_set('memory_limit','4096M');
        $take = 1;

        $make_folder = User::where('status', '>=', '3')->wherenull('remark_restore')->limit($take)->get();

        foreach ($make_folder as $make_folder) {
            $path = public_path().'/file/'.$make_folder->id;

            if(!(file_exists($path))) {
                $data = User::where('id', $make_folder->id)->update(array('remark_restore' => '1' ));
                File::makeDirectory($path, $mode = 0777, true, true);
            }
        }

        $count = User::where('status', '>=', '3')->wherenull('remark_restore')->count();

        echo 'Pending : '.$count;
    }
    catch (\Exception $e) {
        \Log::warning($e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try give delay of creating the folder inside your foreach() function. Example add sleep(5)

Comment: and try adding limit to the query like limit(10) per request.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you are confusing things...

A correct approach here is to dispatch a job for each folder instead of having a single job to do every creation.

So, you should have a Job like `CreateFolderForUser` and in it have something like:

```php
class CreateFolderForUser
{
    protected $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        try {
            $path = public_path("/file/{$this->user->id}");

            if(!(file_exists($path))) {
                File::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true, true);

                $this->user->remark_restore = 1;
                $this->user->save();
            }
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            \Log::warning($e);
        }
    }
}
```

See that I have removed everything about iterating users, you just need to do this job that is "Create a folder for this user", nothing else...

Also, see that I have moved the `remark_restore` update **after** creating the directory, because on your previous code, if the creation fails, you have already updated the user's `remark_restore` to `1` but that is false, you had an error...

---

Now you should have a Scheduler that runs code or do it in a command so the scheduler calls that command every 5 minutes or whatever you want to. This code will see the database and dispatch this job with each user you want to have a folder created.

```php
public function dispatchUserFolderCreation()
{
    $take = 1000;
    $users = User::where('status', '>=', '3')
        ->whereNull('remark_restore')
        ->limit($take)
        ->chunk(100, function (Collection $users) {
            foreach ($users as $user) {
                dispatch(new CreateFolderForUser($user));
            }
        });
}
```

You could dynamically pass the `$take` you want, if you are using a command, so the default is `1000` but if you want less or more (do not send `10000`, do it in batches of `2000`, not more), you can do it.